# Image complete property returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I am trying to adjust the height of a div to fit an image after it is loaded taking into account that the image might be cached.

I am trying to use the image complete property to find out whether the image is already loaded so that i can call the handler function or add the handler function to a load function that will run after the image has fully loaded.

When I call image.complete I am getting undefined.

What could cause this sort of behaviour?

When I was using console.log to inspect the image the complete property was clearly there and had a true value.

```
//functions
var setHeight = function(imageObj){
    var imageHeight = imageObj.height();
    console.log(imageObj);
    console.log(imageHeight);
    displayElement.css("height", imageHeight);
}

var setImageHeight = function(imageObj){
    displayElement.html(imageObj);
    if (imageObj.complete){
        setHeight(imageObj);
    } else {
        imageObj.load(setHeight(imageObj));
    }
}

// define and image, send it to the function to add to html and adjust height.
var imageObj = jQuery('<img class="current-image"/>').attr('src', ...);             
setImageHeight(imageObj);
```

Comment: just use `var img = new Image(); img.src = src; img.onload = function() { // image is loaded }`

Comment: that doesn't work for cases where the image is already in the cache as it is already loaded.

Comment: check for a height, if the height is > 0 then the image is loaded. hacky, but should work.

Comment: I'm asking why the complete property would return undefined. Not for some other hack.

Comment: not sure, it returns fine in my tests on Chrome. if it returns 'undefined' that means the image is not loaded. or element does not exist? There really is no way to tell unless you provide us with more information. like your code.

Comment: Note:   The above code was not working for numerous reasons. I also had to pass this through the load function so that things were scoped right. otherwise the image height kept returning 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`complete` is a property of the underlying DOM element, so to access it you will need to use something like this:

```
if (imageObj[0].complete){
    ...
}
```

This is likely why it is coming up as undefined: `imageObj` (which is a jQuery object) does not itself have this property.

Comment: You are correct. I tested that numerous times because I knew it was in an array. but it kept giving errors when I did that. I suspect i wasn't reading the errors correctly and they were somewhat unrelated. thanks

Comment: Thanks for that answer, felt like I was running around in circles there.